# Is it possible to write a test for an axios request in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, testing, axios

I am learning about testing React components and I have a question. I created a small app where I use
an axios request to get user list and to render it to the DOM.
Is it possible to write a test for that and what should I use? Jest or testing library?

Here is my code :

```
    import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import UserList from './components/Users/UserList';


function App() {

const [users,setUsers] = useState([]);

useEffect(()=>{
  axios.get('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
  .then(response =>{
      setUsers(response.data.data);
      
      
  })
  .catch(error =>{
    console.log(error)
  })
}, [])

  

  return (
    <div>
      
      <UserList users={users} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You'd probably have to mock it at the global level. For example, using a package like this https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-mock-axios could help.

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70450576/how-to-test-react-component-with-axios-request-in-useeffect)