# How to test react component with axios request in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have react functional component with request in useEffect.
https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-dew-r2p1d?file=/src/App.tsx

```
const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<IJoke | undefined>(undefined);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Programming?type=single")
      .then((res: AxiosResponse<IJoke>) => {
        setData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoading ? (
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
      ) : (
        <div className="info">
          <div className="info__cat">
            {data?.category ? `category: ${data.category}` : "bad category"}
          </div>
          <div className="info__joke">
            {data?.joke ? `joke: ${data?.joke}` : "bad data"}
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

How I can cover the component with tests? I need to test state before request, in time and after. How mock request in this context?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Option 1. Use [msw](https://mswjs.io/) to mock by intercepting requests on the network level.

Option 2. If you don't want to install any package and setup, you can use `jest.spyOn(object, 'method').mockResolvedValueOnce()` to create a mock resolved/rejected value for `axios.get()` method.

The below example uses option 2.

`App.tsx`:

```
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

interface IJoke {
  category: string;
  joke: string;
}

export const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState<IJoke | undefined>(undefined);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get('https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Programming?type=single')
      .then((res: AxiosResponse<IJoke>) => {
        setData(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {isLoading ? (
        <h2>Loading...</h2>
      ) : (
        <div className="info">
          <div className="info__cat">{data?.category ? `category: ${data.category}` : 'bad category'}</div>
          <div className="info__joke">{data?.joke ? `joke: ${data?.joke}` : 'bad data'}</div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

`App.test.tsx`:

```
import { App } from './App';
import axios, { AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { act, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import React from 'react';

describe('70450576', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('should render category and joke', async () => {
    const mAxiosResponse = {
      data: { category: 'smart', joke: 'sam' },
    } as AxiosResponse;
    jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce(mAxiosResponse);
    render(<App />);
    expect(screen.getByText('Loading...')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(await screen.findByText('category: smart')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(await screen.findByText('joke: sam')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  examples/70450576/App.test.tsx (8.874 s)
  70450576
    ✓ should render category and joke (43 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   91.67 |    72.22 |      80 |   90.91 |                   
 App.tsx  |   91.67 |    72.22 |      80 |   90.91 | 19                
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.393 s, estimated 10 s
```

Comment: ok, I understand how to test this type of case, thanks)) But, what if we have custom request function, like here [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-dew-r2p1d?file=/src/App.tsx)? How to mock this func?

Comment: @СлаваИванов You import a function from a module, it's not an object, can't use `jest.spyOn(object, 'method')` anymore. Now, you could use `jest.mock("./app.service")` to mock the module. Jest will automatically hoist `jest.mock` calls to the top of the module (before any imports). The `getJoke`  function is mocked, then you can mock the resolved/rejected value in each test case like `getJoke.mockResolvedValueOnce(xxx)`.Besides, you could use the `mocked` helper function from `ts-jest/utils` to make the TS type correct.

Comment: +1 for using MSW. Don't mock implementation details of your request clients/functions. Approach API mocking on a higher level instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access to `state` and `setState` internally that with react-testing-library. This is because RTL wants you to test your component as a user would.
You should try to reproduce the set of actions that change the state.
Use `render` function of `react-testing-library`for rendering components, pass the mocked `state` and `setState` to this component.
Use `axiosMock` from `axios` to mock the axios.
In this approach you can check the mocked values as a real local states.

```
import { render } from "react-testing-library";
import axiosMock from "axios";
```

This link could be helpful:

[async-axios-react-testing-library](https://www.leighhalliday.com/async-axios-react-testing-library)